# Replacing hex in sed (with wildcard?)

Tags: bash, sed, hex

I have a data file from a game with translations in it. The different strings are seperated by 2 bytes HEX. One of those seems random and the other is always `00`

an examples for those "seperators" would be `1F 00` `44 00` `15 00` - as you can see some of those characters are printable.

I have tried to replace the characters in sed `sed -i 's/\x..\x00/\x0D\x0A/g' file.data` but it seems sed with HEX doesn't like wildcards.

I have also thought that I could just replace the `00` with `0D` and then remove the last character of each line, but that didn't work for several of the printable characters.

Here is an example part taken from the data file:

```
s�Block#�%s has been added to your Blacklist�XP�Get Reputation Points�Add to Friends�%s is already your FriendD�Use Magazines to increase Commander's Leadership.
(Success Rate: %s)�Increase Failed'�Leadership successfully upgraded by %d!�Upgrade Leadership
```

HEX:

```
73 05 00 42 6C 6F 63 6B 23 00 25 73 20 68 61 73 20 62 65 65 6E 20 61 64 64 65 64 20 74 6F 20 79 6F 75 72 20 42 6C 61 63 6B 6C 69 73 74 02 00 58 50 15 00 47 65 74 20 52 65 70 75 74 61 74 69 6F 6E 20 50 6F 69 6E 74 73 0E 00 41 64 64 20 74 6F 20 46 72 69 65 6E 64 73 19 00 25 73 20 69 73 20 61 6C 72 65 61 64 79 20 79 6F 75 72 20 46 72 69 65 6E 64 44 00 55 73 65 20 4D 61 67 61 7A 69 6E 65 73 20 74 6F 20 69 6E 63 72 65 61 73 65 20 43 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 65 72 27 73 20 4C 65 61 64 65 72 73 68 69 70 2E 0A 28 53 75 63 63 65 73 73 20 52 61 74 65 3A 20 25 73 29 0F 00 49 6E 63 72 65 61 73 65 20 46 61 69 6C 65 64 27 00 4C 65 61 64 65 72 73 68 69 70 20 73 75 63 63 65 73 73 66 75 6C 6C 79 20 75 70 67 72 61 64 65 64 20 62 79 20 25 64 21 12 00 55 70 67 72 61 64 65 20 4C 65 61 64 65 72 73 68 69 70
```

Maybe I am too tired to come up with a solution or I am missing something obvious. Would be great if anyone could give me a hint.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Figured it out. Might be a bit complicated but works in my case:

```
xxd -p file.data | tr -d '\n' > file.hex  ---> Convert binary to hex, strip new lines
sed -i 's/.\{2\}/& /g' file.hex           ---> add spaces every 2 bits so we don't compare the second half of bit 1 with the first half of bit 2
sed -i 's/.. 0a/0d 0a/g' file.hex         ---> replace .. 0a with CR/LF
sed -i 's/.. 00/0d 0a/g' file.hex         ---> replace .. 00 with CR/LF
xxd -p -r file.hex file2.data             ---> convert the hex back to binary. luckily xxd doesn't care about the missing new lines or added spaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/�/ /g' file.data

sed -i 's/.. 00/0D 0A/g' file.hex
```

WOMM, but please let me know your results.

Comment: Did not work. From my understanding this would only replace the STRING `.. 00` not the hex. but I figured it out thanks to your hint with .hex ...... I converted the file with xxd first - see inital post.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Might be a bit complicated but works in my case:

```
xxd -p file.data | tr -d '\n' > file.hex  ---> Convert binary to hex, strip new lines
sed -i 's/.\{2\}/& /g' file.hex           ---> add spaces every 2 bits so we don't compare the second half of bit 1 with the first half of bit 2
sed -i 's/.. 0a/0d 0a/g' file.hex         ---> replace .. 0a with CR/LF
sed -i 's/.. 00/0d 0a/g' file.hex         ---> replace .. 00 with CR/LF
xxd -p -r file.hex file2.data             ---> convert the hex back to binary. luckily xxd doesn't care about the missing new lines or added spaces.
```